# IDE0005 not reported as build failure even with GenerateDocumentationFile set to true

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop, editorconfig

I want the build of my project to fail if there are unused usings. In csproj I have added:

```
<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
```

Following the solution mentioned in https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/41640
In .editorconfig I have added:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0005.severity = error
```

However the build still doesn't fail. The errors are reported in the IDE but the build succeeds.
[image]

[image]

Could someone let me know what am I missing here? I am using visual studio 2022.

Comment: Maybe CS8019 has been set to none? This analyser is needed for IDE0005. If so, set CS8019  to hidden / silent.